# Как забиндиться на порт

Tags: python

Стоит задача с помощью питона просто занять UDP 53 port. Резолвить ничего не требуется.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону дефолтного [**socket.**](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) В таком случае забиндиться на порт можно с помощью команды `bind(...)` у соответствующего объекта.

Не забудьте, кстати, про использование `shutdown()` и `close()`, иначе поведение скрипта становится `OS-specific`.

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался

import socket

_IP="127.0.0.1"
_PORT=53

sockUDP = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) 
sockTCP = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP
sockUDP.bind( (_IP,_PORT) )

sockTCP.bind( (_IP,_PORT) )
sockTCP.listen(1)